# JSP text field read only

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

Please tell me how to make JSP text filed read only using JSP ? In html we can use

```
<input type = "text" name="someName" readonly/>
```

But how can we do the same thing using JSP.(If I want to disable text field based on user account type?)

Comment: maybe you return value from object liek(Request or session )have value of read only or not and put it as readonly in tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `readOnly`attribute according to parameter, for example

```
String readOnly = "CAN_READ".equals(request.getParameter("userAccountType")) ? "readOnly" : "";
```

And use it in input:

```
<input type = "text" name="someName"<%=readOnly%> />
```